# Proof of prime numbers in the form..

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

There exists a unique prime in the form of p^2 -1, p is just some integer with the restriction of p being greater than or equal to 2. Prove this.

I understand that I am first suppose show a prime p exists and that another p' exists then p=p'.But I am quite confused.

Comment: It is not quite clear for me what you are asking, but perhaps this is helpful: $a^2-1 = (a-1)(a+1)$

Comment: @Improve: That sounds good enough, as it implies that the only (unique) prime of this form is $3$, which occurs when $a-1=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[p^2-1\text{ is prime}]\wedge[p\geq2]\iff$

$[(p-1)(p+1)\text{ is prime}]\wedge[p\geq2]\iff$

$([p-1=1]\vee[p+1=1])\wedge[p\geq2]\iff$

$([p=2]\vee[p=0])\wedge[p\geq2]\iff$

$[p=2]$

Hence the only prime of the form $p^2-1$ is $2^2-1=3$.